# ¿Como hago para llamar a un metodo de otra clase , se puede ? JAVA POO

Tags: java, poo

Buenasss estoy haciendo un programa acerca de una estadisticas de personas sobre el peso , y debo evaluar peso normal , bajo , sobre peso , promedio , cantidad , etc.

Pero tengo un problema en  la clase estadistica en los metodos :  pesoPromedio cantidadPesoBajo , cantidadPesoNormal , cantidadSobrePeso.
Me sale error cuando utilizo lo siguiente en cada metodo : Persona.getPeso()
y en consola me sale : error non-static method getAltura() getPeso() cannot be referenced from static context .
Lo que trate de hacer es llamar al método getPeso y getAltura de la clase Persona para poder calcular el peso/altura que voy ingresando por cada objeto.
No se si lo que hice se puede o quizás lo hice mal.

A continuacion les voy a dejar el codigo de la clase persona y estadistica :

```
    public class Persona{

    private  String nombre;
    private int edad;
    private  double altura ;
    private  double peso;

    public Persona(String nom , int ed , double alt  , double peso){

        this.nombre = nom;
        this.edad = ed;
        this.altura = alt;
        this.peso = peso;
    } 


public  int getEdad(){

    return this.edad;
}

public  void setEdad(int edad){

    this.edad= edad;
}
public String getnombre(){

    return this.nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre){

    this.nombre= nombre;
}

public double getAltura(){

    return this.altura;
}

public void setAltura(double altura){

    this.altura= altura;
}

public double getPeso(){

    return this.peso;
}

public void setPeso(double peso){

    this.peso= peso;
}


}

    public class EstadisticaDePersonas{

    private String nombre;
    private int cantidadDeMuestra;


    public EstadisticaDePersonas(String nombre , int cantidad){

        this.nombre = nombre ;
        this.cantidadDeMuestra = cantidad;
    } 


    public boolean pesoBajo(Persona persona){

        int imc= 0;
        boolean estado = false;
        imc = (int) persona.getPeso() /(int) (persona.getAltura()*persona.getAltura());

        if(imc <=18){

          estado = true;

        }

        else{

            estado= false;
        }


    }

    public boolean pesoNormal(Persona persona){

        int imc = 0;
        boolean estado = false;
        imc = (int) persona.getPeso() /(int) (persona.getAltura()*persona.getAltura());

        if(imc >=18 && imc<=24){

          estado = true;

        }

        else{

            estado= false;
        }
        }


        public boolean sobrePeso(Persona persona){

         int imc = 0;
        boolean estado = false;
        imc = (int) persona.getPeso() /(int) (persona.getAltura()*persona.getAltura());

        if(imc >=25){

          estado = true;

        }

        else{

            estado= false;
        }


    }


    public double pesoPromedio(){


        double promedio=0.0d;
        int contadorPeso=0;
        int sumatoria =0 ;

        if(Persona.getPeso()>0){

            contadorPeso++; }

          sumatoria+=contadorPeso;

        return promedio = contadorPeso/this.cantidadDeMuestra;

    }

    public int cantidadPesoBajo(){
        int pesoBajo =0;
        final int imc = 0;
        imc = (int) Persona.getPeso() /(int) (Persona.getAltura()*Persona.getAltura());


        if(imc<=18){

            pesoBajo++;

        }

        return pesoBajo;
    }


public int cantidadPesoNormal(){
        int pesoNormal =0;
        final int imc = 0;
        imc = (int) Persona.getPeso() /(int) (Persona.getAltura()*Persona.getAltura());

        if(imc >=18 && imc<=24){

            pesoNormal++;

        }

        return pesoNormal;
    }

public int cantidadSobrePeso(){
        int sobrePeso =0;
        final int imc = 0;
        imc = (int) Persona.getPeso() /(int) (Persona.getAltura()*Persona.getAltura());

        if(imc >=25){

            sobrePeso++;

        }

        return sobrePeso;
    }


public double promedioBajoPeso(){

double promedio =0.0;

return promedio = cantidadPesoBajo()/this.cantidadDeMuestra;


}

public double promedioSobrePaso(){

double promedio =0.0;

return promedio = cantidadSobrePeso()/this.cantidadDeMuestra;


}


}
```

Si alguien puede explicarme en que falle , gracias :)

Answer (score 1):

Lo que debes hacer es crear un objeto de la clase que quieres llamar ejemplo

```
Persona persona_Uno=new Persona;
```

Aqui instanciamos un objeto que tendra los atributos y metodos que tu deseas (ten en cuenta el tipo de acceso que se tine en los atributos y metodo para poder trabajar con ellos, para trabajar con algun metodo solo usamos el objeto

```
 persona_Uno.<El metodo que quieres(Parametros)>
```